# Problem with Wordpress permalinks

Tags: htaccess, regex

We have set our permalinks so that it displays like this:

- `example.com/iphones/` **for categories**    and
- `example.com/iphones/iphone-11-Pro`      **for the products.**

The problem that the old native URLs of WordPress example:

- `example.com/category-product/iphones`     **For categories**

is not redirected to 404 (which is normal since we are no longer configured on it) but rather displays the first product of the category of the URL entered eg :
`example.com/category-product/iphones` will directly display a product.

So we want to redirect this URL:

- `example.com/category-product/iphones`

to

- `example.com/iphones` (as categories)

Comment: Is `-product` a fixed/literal string and `category` is variable? Or is the whole path segment `category-products` literal text which simply needs to be removed? Should the target category URL end with a trailing slash (as in your first sentence), or omit it (as in your last sentence)?

Comment: No, product are variables that refer to the products of the site.
Yes the categories are variables there are several categories on the site.

We want to delete the segment
* / category-product / *
It is a variable of in the base of url of wordpress

The slashes are accessory in this case.
Basically we just want to have all the old urls
* domain.com / category-product / iphones / iphone-11-pro *
redirected to new
* domain.com / iphones / iphone-11-pro *

Comment: Can `product` and `category` themselves contain _hyphens_ (`-`)? Otherwise, it's not clear how you can differentiate between the "old category URL" and the "new product URL", as they seem to follow a similar format. Can "category" contain hyphens? In your comment you've introduced another URL format: the "old product URL" by the looks, which isn't mentioned in your question?

Comment: Hi, Here is the links of screenshots of the issues specifily detailled.
1 - https://www.hebergeur-image.fr/photo.php?id=d04316afc96b87cbca01370a6b9dfaf2071fc906

2 - https://www.hebergeur-image.fr/photo.php?id=6d977df6769a567fd78e38c985a6a953e8ae15e0

3 - https://www.hebergeur-image.fr/photo.php?id=8e5c1720d500a77227aa9e60bf366d4ea3a4435d

4 - https://www.hebergeur-image.fr/photo.php?id=d41f2d277ce72f3b3949c223d4ffdb9730cf632c

5 - https://www.hebergeur-image.fr/photo.php?id=31e7f114f1fb007b3e963fed947a4608d37978fa

two links left

Comment: 6 - [link](https://www.hebergeur-image.fr/photo.php?id=5432eec8e3e117bf6bfc6562ec6203438cbc04b9)
/
7 - [link](https://www.hebergeur-image.fr/photo.php?id=60c89443d64c47d75de5f5332e596dc8da6d4272)

right this how we configure ou permalinks and how its works and what we get instead of getting 404 page. 


Let me know if you need more informations.

Comment: Please add the additional information to your question as plain-text, rather than linking to 7(!) external screenshots.

Comment: in summary I would like to know how we can write htaccess so that this url:
konnectek-mobile.com/category-product/category-name be redirected like this:
konnectek-mobile.com/category-name
which mean konnectek-mobile.com/category-name/iphone will be rewrite to konnectek-mobile.com/iphone

Thank you !